# Is it possible to set a default value of zero when using COUNTA function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm using a pivot table in a Google Spreadsheet that counts the occurrences of different types of event-types on given dates.  The events are listed on one sheet, with a column for "Date" and column for "Type."  Based on this a Pivot Table is produced.

The trouble is that for dates when an event-type is non-existent, COUNTA returns empty.  I'd rather it return 0.

The reason is for charting and statistical purposes when you create a chart from this data, it interpolates between values, ignoring empty cells.  I'd prefer that it display zero on the chart on the days when these event types don't exist...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD: sorry, I've misunderstood what you need.
What if, on another worksheet, you write the following?

```
=arrayformula(IF('PivotSheetName'!A1:Z100="";0;'PivotSheetName'!A1:Z100))
```

(This formula makes a copy of your Pivot table on the new worksheet,
replacing empty cells with 0; moreover, the control elements of the
pivot table are copied to the new worksheet as well)

Comment: Sounds promising, except in Google docs the pivot tables are semi-automated.  You select "Create a pivot table" from a dropdown menu, and "COUNTA" is an option amongst a longer list (no custom options).

Comment: Cool.. It solves my zero problem, but now it replaces all the empty cells across the sheet with zeros =P.  The good thing about the pivot table is that it automatically updates, and the chart just plots the entire sheet (skipping the empty cells), so that I don't have to go back and change the data range for the chart.  Do you have thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Thanks.  Sort of an indirect method (still interested in a more direct solution...) but this does indeed solve my problem.